# uninitialized constant MoviesController

Tags: initialization, constants

I Have code and using rails version 5.1.1

Code file routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "movies#index"
  resources :movies, only: [:index, :create]
end
```

Code file app\controllers\movies_controller.rb

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
      def index
      end

      def create
        url = params[:url]
        @links = GoogleDrive.list_link_videos url
        render :index
      end
 end
```

When I run Then It is show error "uninitialized constant MoviesController"

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: check your filename agai...is it movies_controller.rb?

Comment: run command `rake routes` and paste  your all routes